# when i am using Microsoft.Expression.Encoder in visual studio c# I am Getting error

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

when i am using Microsoft.Expression.Encoder in visual studio c# I am Getting error

threw an exception. -> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Expression.Encoder, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
  System.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't resolved it already, try changing the **Project Platform** from **x64** to **x86**.

Comment: Changing the Project Platform solved my issue. If it throws the same exception then I can recommend that maybe you can create a new project and set the target platform to x86 and then try adding Expression.Encoder's files into the project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Encoder form [here](https://www.microsoft.com/de-DE/download/details.aspx?id=18974).

Microsoft Expression Encoder is no longer available in NuGet

Comment: The link you posted seems to be dead.